# how to use dynamic title in kendo grid - jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Below is my code and currently for column titles I've hard-coded the weekdays. But I need to make it dynamic and display the titles as per the date changes. How can I display the js variable 'weekdate' as the title for each column? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
$("#grid-report-store").kendoGrid({
        noRecords: true,
        dataSource: grid_data_source_store(weekstart,weekend),
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filterable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "EmployeeId", title: "Employee Id", width: 100},
            { field: "EmployeeName", title: "Employee Name", width: 100},
            { title: "Sunday", width: 120, filterable:false, template: function(dataItem) {
                var weekdate = 'Day'+moment(weekstart).add(0, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD');
                return (dataItem[weekdate])?dataItem[weekdate]:'';
            }},
            { title: "Monday", width: 120, filterable:false, template: function(dataItem) {
                var weekdate = 'Day'+moment(weekstart).add(1, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD');
                return (dataItem[weekdate])?dataItem[weekdate]:'';
            }},
            { title: "Tuesday", width: 120, filterable:false, template: function(dataItem) {
                var weekdate = 'Day'+moment(weekstart).add(2, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD');
                return (dataItem[weekdate])?dataItem[weekdate]:'';
            }},
            { title: "Wednesday", width: 120, filterable:false, template: function(dataItem) {
                var weekdate = 'Day'+moment(weekstart).add(3, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD');
                return (dataItem[weekdate])?dataItem[weekdate]:'';
            }},
            { title: "Thursday", width: 120, filterable:false, template: function(dataItem) {
                var weekdate = 'Day'+moment(weekstart).add(4, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD');
                return (dataItem[weekdate])?dataItem[weekdate]:'';
            }},
            { title: "Friday", width: 120, filterable:false, template: function(dataItem) {
                var weekdate = 'Day'+moment(weekstart).add(5, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD');
                return (dataItem[weekdate])?dataItem[weekdate]:'';
            }},
            { title: "Saturday", width: 120, filterable:false, template: function(dataItem) {
                var weekdate = 'Day'+moment(weekstart).add(6, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD');
                return (dataItem[weekdate])?dataItem[weekdate]:'';
            }},
            { field: "TotalHours", title: "Total Hours", width: 100},
            { field: "OTHours", title: "O/T Hours", width: 100},
        ],
        dataBound: function(e) {
            $(".k-group-footer").css("text-align", "right" );
            $(".w").addClass("btn btn-success" );
            $(".d").addClass("btn btn-danger" );
            $(".p").addClass("btn btn-warning" );
            $(".u").addClass("btn btn-warning" );
            $(".w-o").addClass("btn btn-warning" );

            kendo.ui.progress($("#grid-report-store").css('padding', '0'), false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you use the column's headerTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Get the fields from the grid's datasource's options's schema's model
2. Map the array to your desired format (e.g. field, title, filterable, template)
3. Set the columns property of the grid

Take a look at this example:

```js
var dataSource = grid_data_source_store(weekstart,weekend)
var columns = Object
  .keys(dataSource.options.schema.model.fields)
  .filter(function(field) {
      return field !== 'EmployeeId' && field !== 'EmployeeName' && field !== 'TotalHours' && field !== 'OTHours';
  })
  .map(function(field) {
    return {
      field: field,
      title: field,
      width: 120,
      filterable: false,
      template: function(dataItem) {
        var weekdate = 'Day' + moment(weekstart).add(0, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD');
        return (dataItem[weekdate])?dataItem[weekdate]:'';
      }
    }
  });
columns.unshift({ field: 'EmployeeId', title: 'Employee Id', width: 100 });
columns.unshift({ field: 'EmployeeName', title: 'Employee Name', width: 100 });
columns.push({ field: 'TotalHours', title: 'Total Hours', width: 100 });
columns.push({ field: 'OTHours', title: '"O/T Hours', width: 100 });


$("#grid-report-store").kendoGrid({
  noRecords: true,
  dataSource: dataSource,
  sortable: true,
  resizable: true,
  filterable: true,
  columns: columns,
  dataBound: function(e) {
    $(".k-group-footer").css("text-align", "right" );
    $(".w").addClass("btn btn-success" );
    $(".d").addClass("btn btn-danger" );
    $(".p").addClass("btn btn-warning" );
    $(".u").addClass("btn btn-warning" );
    $(".w-o").addClass("btn btn-warning" );

    kendo.ui.progress($("#grid-report-store").css('padding', '0'), false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but unfortunately, I couldn't use this method as I have to update the grid data and column titles also based on a date picker change, so am updating the titles using jquery!

Comment: @NasmaNajeeb - To clarify, all of my code is either jQuery or vanilla JavaScript. If you're uncomfortable with the latter, then use the jQuery counter-parts. As far as changing the data and column titles based on a date picker change, instead of reinitializing the grid, simply call `setOptions` using the mapped column data.